# Making laravel system 7 based on laravel 5.3 system but can't log in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

When I press login after setting email and password it only blinks and nothing else happens. I have a A Larvel Passport system with Oauth2 login.

This is a working system but in V. 5.3: https://test.webshooter.se In the Laravel 7 system I can do everything like show competitions, map, register users, reset passwords, and get emails to and from but is not able to login. I have come so far that the user is authenticated in such a way that there is both oauth_refresh_tokens and oauth_access_tokens registred in the database for every login clicked.

Here is the login blade:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{_('Logga in')}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div ng-class="{'hide': loggingIn}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="auth.email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{{_('E-postadress')}}" ng-enter="login();" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="auth.password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{_('Lösenord')}}" ng-enter="login();">
                    </div>

                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="login();" ng-class="{'disabled': loggingIn}">{{_('LOGIN')}}</a>
                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <a ui-sref="auth.password">{{_('Glömt ditt lösenord?')}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row margin-top-20">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <a ui-sref="auth.register">{{_('Inget konto? Registrera dig')}} &raquo;</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="hide text-center text-muted" ng-class="{show: loggingIn}">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                    <p>{{_('LOGGING IN')}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>

<script>$('#email').focus();</script>
```

This is part of the AuthenticateController:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Jobs\SendActivationEmail;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\UserInvite;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
 
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = \JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials', 'message' => _('Vänligen kontrollera ditt användarnamn och/eller lösenord.')], 401);
            } elseif (JWTAuth::toUser($token)->activation_code && JWTAuth::toUser($token)->created_at < date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 weeks'))) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'user_inactive', 'message' => _('Din e-postadress har inte aktiverats ännu. Du bör ha ett e-postmeddelande innehållande en aktiveringslänk.')], 401);
            } elseif (JWTAuth::toUser($token)->deleted_at) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'user_deleted', 'message' => _('Ditt konto har inaktiverats. Ta kontakt med vår kundsupport om du vill återaktivera ditt konto.')], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token', 'message' => _('Någonting verkar ha gått ha fel. Prova gärna igen.')], 500);
        }
        $user = \Auth::user();
        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
        return response()->json(compact('token','user'));
    }

    public function updatePassword(Requests\PasswordRequest $request)
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        if(\Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)):
            return response()->json(['message'=>_('Nuvarande lösenord verkar inte stämma.')], 401);
        else:
            $user->update(['password'=>bcrypt($request->get('password'))]);
            return response()->json(['message'=>_('Ditt lösenord har ändrats')]);
        endif;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function getAuthenticatedUser(){
        $user = \Auth::user();

        $user->makeVisible([
            'email',
            'no_shooting_card_number',
            'shooting_card_number',
            'birthday',
            'phone',
            'mobile',
            'gender',
            'grade_trackshooting',
            'grade_field'
        ]);
        // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }

    public function updateAuthenticatedUser(\App\Http\Requests\UserRequest $request){
        try {

            $user = \Auth::user();
            $data = $request->all();
            if($request->has('set_no_shooting_card_number')) $data['no_shooting_card_number'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if($request->has('shooting_card_number')) $data['no_shooting_card_number'] = null;
            $user->update($data);
            $user->makeVisible([
                'email',
                'no_shooting_card_number',
                'shooting_card_number',
                'birthday',
                'phone',
                'mobile',
                'gender',
                'grade_trackshooting',
                'grade_field'
            ]);
            return response()->json(compact('user'));

        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
            } else if ($e instanceof TokenBlacklistedException) {
                return response()->json(['token_blacklisted'], $e->getStatusCode());
            } else if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
                return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
            } else if ($e instanceof PayloadException) {
                return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
            } else if ($e instanceof JWTException) {
                return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public function register(\App\Http\Requests\RegistrationRequest $request){

        try {
            //Verify recaptcha request.
            $verifyUrl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $verifyUrl .= '?hl=sv_SE';
            $verifyUrl .= '&secret='.env('RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY');
            $verifyUrl .= '&response='.$request->get('recaptcharesponse');
            $recaptchaResponse = json_decode(file_get_contents($verifyUrl), true);
            if(!isset($recaptchaResponse['success']) || $recaptchaResponse['success'] !== true):
                return response()->json(['error' => 'recaptcha_error', 'message' => _('Någonting gick fel, vänligen försök igen.')], 500);
            endif;
            
            $data = $request->all();
            $data['activation_code'] = md5($data['email'].time());
            $data['password'] = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
            $data['language'] = \App\Models\Languages::defaultLanguage();

            $user = User::create($data);

            /**
             * Get userinvite based on email address and update the invite with a timestamp.
             * If the request has an invite_token check if the token is present as an id.
             */
            $inviteQuery = Userinvite::where('email', $request->get('email'));
    /*        if($request->has('invite_token')):
                $optimus = new \Jenssegers\Optimus\Optimus(env('OPTIMUS_PRIME'), env('OPTIMUS_INVERSE'), env('OPTIMUS_RANDOM'));
                $inviteId = $optimus->decode($request->get('invite_token'));
                $inviteQuery->orWhere('id', $inviteId);
            endif;*/
            if($invite = $inviteQuery->first()):
                $invite->update(['registered_at'=>$user->created_at]);
            endif;

            /**
             * Send activation e-mail works 2021-12-16
             */
            if(env('APP_ENV') == 'local'):
                $this->dispatch(new SendActivationEmail($user));
            endif;
            return response()->json('success');
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Fel vid registrering', 'message' => _('Någonting gick fel, vänligen försök igen.')], 500);
        }

    }

    public function cancelAccount()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
```

First part of the routes (routes/api.php):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the \\  RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('/auth/register', ['as'=>'auth.register', 'uses'=>'Controllers/AuthenticateController@register']);

Route::group(['prefix'=>'v'.env('API_VERSION')], function(){
    Route::post('activate', 'AuthenticateController@activate');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthenticateController@register');
    #Route::post('refresh', 'AuthenticateController@refresh');
    Route::post('password/email', 'PasswordController@postEmail');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'PasswordController@postReset');

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'public'], function(){
    Route::resource('competitions', 'PublicCompetitionsController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    });


    Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api', 'checkUserActive']], function(){
 
        Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');
        Route::put('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@updateAuthenticatedUser');
        Route::put('authenticate/updatePassword', 'AuthenticateController@updatePassword');
        Route::post('authenticate/cancelAccount', 'AuthenticateController@cancelAccount');
        Route::get('users/invite', 'AuthenticateController@getInvite');
        Route::post('users/invite', 'AuthenticateController@sendInvite');
        Route::put('clubs', ['as'=>'clubs.update', 'uses'=>'ClubsController@update']);
        Route::get('clubs/getUserClub', ['as'=>'clubs.getUserClub', 'uses'=>'ClubsController@getUserClub']);
        Route::post('clubs/addNewClub', ['as'=>'clubs.addNewClub', 'uses'=>'ClubsController@addNewClub']);
```

Getting this error when trying to login:

```
[2021-12-30 13:59:38] local.ERROR: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable {"userId":11,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable at /Users/ralph/onsdagWS7/webshooter_web_upgrade/app/Models/User.php:96)
[stacktrace]
```

And in the user.php:

```
    public function getClubsIdAttribute()
    {
        if(!$this->relationLoaded('Clubs')):
            $this->load('Clubs');
        endif;

(96)        return (count($this->Clubs->first())) ? $this->Clubs->first()->id : null;
    }
```

What could be the problem? But I don't get into the dashboard blade when clicking "Login" but it returns directly back to the login page.

Comment: I don't see any problems in your site. I could register successfully with no error https://ibb.co/1Zk9kw0

Comment: Yes, register a user works perfect even in my ver. 7,  it's login that doesn't work. I will now update the list of  the AuthenticateController as I got the wrong part in there. But you were using  https://test.webshooter.se to do that and there everything works perfect but is in Laravel 5.3 version.  I saw that you were registred. This I am talking about is a local setup in Laravel 7 described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue anymore. I have successfully upgraded the system to Laravel 9.17.0 present version.